Ошибка при команде npm install npm start
скачал данный проект, backend запустил успешно. А вот frontend выдаёт ошибку если идти по инструкции с гитхата и использовать команду "npm install npm start".
Как я могу устранить данную ошибку или обойти её?
Код ошибки:


Какая то из используемых библитотек не имеет явной версии и что то установилось очень новое, что другая библиотека не поддерживает. Попробуйте в package.json в зависимостях указать точные номера версий, без ^
